# What happens if there is a 0 at the beginning of a http message

Tags: http, google-chrome, http-headers

I am facing the issue of files being downloaded by the browser without rendering them. This happens in Chrome. I have investigated about this and removed all the plugins in Chrome because some say this happens with certain plugins. But the issue still occurs.

So, I had a look at a downloaded file. Note the 0 at the beginning. Can this 0 play a role in this scenario. Does the browser considers it as the header section and try to read the headers and finds nothing. Then consider the rest of the message as the body? Can this be the reason for file being downloaded by the browser instead of rendering it?

```
0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4B4399DD1E8FA49FB17B6DC9A650DAF8; Path=/cloudmgt/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 28 Feb 2014 08:07:09 GMT
Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

{Here comes the gzipped content. I have omitted that to keep this short.}
0
```

Following are the request headers.

```
Request URL: https://mysite.com/pages/index.jsp  
Request Method: GET  
Status Code:200 OK  
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch  
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8  
Connection:keep-alive  
Cookie:JSESSIONID=D4F2E51261E81DDAA3C70FDB96A30A84; __utma=213501382.1702684681.1392966199.1392966199.1393574823.2; __utmb=213501382.2.10.1393574823; __utmc=213501382; __utmz=213501382.1393574823.2.2.utmcsr=mysite.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/commonauth  
Host:mysite.com  
Referer:https://mysite.com/  
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: That is chunked transfer, where a chunk of size `0` denotes the end of the previous response, so that is not the cause of your problem. What kind of file are you trying to display and with what headers do you do so?

Comment: But, why that 0 appears in this message. AFAIK, a http message should start with headers (there cannot be anything before that). If the message is chunked, it expects to see a 0 at the end of the message. But in my case, there is a 0 at the very beginning and at the bottom. This happens for many file types including JSP. But not always. I believe there is something to do with the software loadbalancer (WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer) used in my deployment. I want to fix it and thats why I am trying to identify the root cause of this behaviour.

Comment: I have edited the post with request headers.